# Datatype Map: Extract several atomic values

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I am looking to see if "parse-json" can be an option to "json-to-xml" when comes to extracting data from parsed JSON and if "parse-json" can extract more then 1 value, utlizing a "for-each" loop.

**JSON file:**

```
<data>
{
    "weather": "Sunny",
    "greetings": {
      "english": "hello",
      "spanish": "hola"
    }
  }
</data>
```

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:transform
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:root="http://www.example.org/0"
  xmlns:wheather="http://www.example.org/1"
  xmlns:greetings="http://www.example.org/2"
  xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- Test [1] Extract single value using "parse-json" -->

  <!-- <xsl:template match="data">
    <root:report>
      <xsl:variable name="json" select="parse-json(.)"/>
      <greetings:test>{$json?weather}</greetings:test>
    </root:report>
  </xsl:template> -->

  <!-- Test [2] Extract many value using "parse-json" -->

  <xsl:template match="data">
    <xsl:variable name="map" select="parse-json(.)"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="map:keys($map)">
      <entry key="{.}" value="{$map(.)}"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Result**

Blank / Nothing

**Error**

```
Saxon-HE 10.5J from Saxonica
Java version 11.0.11
Stylesheet compilation time: 350.912306ms
Processing file:[Xxx]
Using parser com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser
Building tree for file:[Xxx] using class net.sf.saxon.tree.tiny.TinyBuilder
Error in entry/@value on line 28 column 43 of principal.xsl:
  FOTY0013  Cannot atomize a map (map{"spanish":"hola","english":"hello"})
     invoked by xsl:for-each at file:[Xxx]
  In template rule with match="data" on line 25 of principal.xsl
     invoked by built-in template rule (text-only)
Cannot atomize a map (map{"spanish":"hola","english":"hello"})
[Finished in 0.879s]
```

Comment: What is the expected result for the attribute value when the JSON does have an object or the XDM does have a map and not a string or number?

Comment: So while your subject asks about atomic values the problem is caused by the JSON object `{ "english": "hello", "spanish": "hola" }` represented in XPath as a map. It is not clear what kind of default processing you expect there.

Comment: I am looking to see if "parse-json" can be an option to "json-to-xml" when comes to extracting data from parsed JSON and if "parse-json" can extract more then 1 value, utlizing a "for-each" loop. Updated the question title.

Comment: A hierarchic structure like nested objects or nested maps are usually not processed by a single `for-each` or `apply-templates`, you need recursion to hande arbitrary nesting. Or a clear desciption on how to serialize a nested map to a single attribute value.

Comment: I think that's a reasonable answer. Please move it to an answer and I will accept it. Just looking to have a clear understanding of functions for JSON parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hierarchic structure like nested objects or nested maps are usually not processed by a single `for-each` or `apply-templates`, you need recursion to hande arbitrary nesting. Or a clear desciption on how to serialize a nested map to a single attribute value.

Of course in the case of XPath navigation using e.g. `//` or `descendant` you can easily process and flatten a hierarchy. There is no similar downwards selection through the hierarchy of XDM maps; it can be implemented however using `map:for-each` and recursion.

Comment: There is map:find() which searches recursively, but it's rather limited, and I rarely use it.

Comment: @MichaelKay, yes, I thought about it but as it looks for a particular key recursively I couldn't come up with a simple suggestions to throw it into the `for-each` example in the question.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with this code?

```
<xsl:for-each select="map:keys($map)">
  <entry key="{.}" value="{$map(.)}"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

It's trying to handle all the entries in a map, but the use of `"{$map(.)}"` means that it only works for entries that can be represented as atomic values - that is, it fails for entries that are maps. If you want to keep your code generic, then you need to test the type of `$map(.)` using instance-of before deciding how to process it. Alternatively you could use the serialize() function to display each value in JSON format - but that rather depends on what you're trying to achieve.